# Terraform - how to add a resource?

Tags: azure, terraform

I crated an environment using Terraform script, and then I'd like to add another resource of the same type I already have. For example, I have 2 instances of my app VM and I'd like to add another one. What would be the way to do so? Updating someway my current script? Add a specific script?

For example:

I have the following resource in which for the first time I created 2 instances of it (var.instances_number = 2). Now I need to have one more.

```
resource "azurerm_virtual_machine" "myApp-vm" {
  count                 = "${var.instances_number}"
  name                  = "${var.prefix}-${var.env_type}-pc${var.myApp_podc}-p0${var.myApp_pod + count.index}-aw-cm01-n01"
  resource_group_name   = "${azurerm_resource_group.main.name}"

...

}
```

Best regards, Tal

Comment: These are two separate questions and as such should be asked separately. Addressing the first for now it would help if you could provide your code and show what you've tried to achieve your goals, showing any errors you get or explaining how your attempted solution didn't provide what you wanted and show what you did get instead.

Comment: @ydaetskcoR done

Comment: So what's wrong with updating your `instances_number` variable? What does a plan show when you do that?

Comment: @ydaetskcoR Nothing is wrong. You are correct. I just found it out.. Thanks

Answer (score 1):

Terraform codes are written in a declarative style, that is they declares the end state of any infrastructure. Terraform is always aware of any states it created in past, and hence if you change a bit of configuration it will add/delete those many resources to bring the current state as per declared in the configuration.

Coming to your question, you want to create total 3 VMs of which two are already created. The correct way to do this is to update the count as 3.
In this case, you should update the instances_number to 3 in your variables.tf file.

Since terraform already knows that it created 2 VMs and the end state should be 3 VMs, it'll add 1 VM, which you can check by executing "terraform plan".

Answer (score 0):

The answer as I just found out is to simply increase the value of instances_number and then terraform will add the missing apps